# Determine if a path is relative or absolute in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a good a method out there that will check to see if a string is a relative path

Examples:

> path = "/absolute/path/to";
>
> path = "relative/path/to"
>
> path = "http://www.absolutePathAsWellWithoutTrailingSlash.com"
>
> path = "file:///www.absolutePathAsWellWithoutTrailingSlash.com"

You can see that checking just for a start slash won't do, to determine if it is absolute or relative.

Is there a good method for this out there, or should I write it myself?

Comment: Check if the first character is a slash?

Comment: I would check for the scheme and the two slashes and colon maybe (off top of my head).

Comment: @ColeJohnson that won't do unfortunately, as mentioned in the question  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you could use a regex:

```
function isPathAbsolute(path) {
  return /^(?:\/|[a-z]+:\/\/)/.test(path);
}
```

Comment: That looks good. Probably better than relying on the DOM.

Comment: Great sabof, I was in one the same line ... improvement tip, use test and (?: non grouping, not that matters in test but perhaps it might speed things up :p

Comment: I suppose that would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: Almost! The test method is unfortunately on the RegExp object :)

Comment: isn't path a String, and since when did Strings have a test method? how can a non-working answer get accepted?

Comment: @dandavis haha ... i was 8 seconds quicker :p

Comment: actually I think double slashes in the beginning might also be considered absolute. I will add it to your answer if that is ok? Sorry, one might also consider adding support for uppercase characters for the protocols...

Comment: @Hamidam The regex will match paths beginning with a double slash as it is.

Comment: @sabof yes that is true, silly me :D

Comment: Note that URI schemes may contain digits (eg. `ed2k://`) and are not always followed by `://` (eg `mailto:`, `javascript:`). The following pattern should do the job: `/^(?:\/|[a-z0-9]+:)/`

Comment: /^(?:\/|[a-z]+:\/\/)/.test("/test/") returns true...

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may work (I have not tested this):

```
function isAbsolute(path){
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = path;
    return a.host !== location.host || a.protocol !== location.protocol;
}
```

Note that if the absolute url points to the same domain and protocol as the current page, this will return false.

Comment: note that a.host is a relatively new property...

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
new RegExp("^(?:/|.+://)").test(path)
```

supports all mentioned in the question and:

path = "//same/as/the/protocol.com/abc

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: How so? It returns true if absolute and false if relative

Comment: I got the impression that you did not answer your own question but just put something that you had but was not working in an answer instead of in your original question (which then should have been an edit to your question or a comment). I apologize if this is not the case. Please remove the "This is what I have as of now" if this is a working solution, just to avoid future confusion.

Comment: new RegExp("^(?:/|.+://)").test('http://www.goole.de') will return true...

Comment: @momomo i meant new RegExp("^(?:/|.+://)").test('http://goole.de')

Comment: somehow stackoverflow is removing "http://". pass http:// before google.de to the test method

Comment: @flowest I would say that is an absolute url though?